# how to write regular expression in python ? I want to write R.E. for the following example

Tags: python, regex, string

If input string is like :

```
"that`s not good thing ! you havn`t understand anything ?"
```

I want to convert it into :

```
" thats not good thing you havnt understand anything "
```

Is this what i want ?

I try the following reg.exp.

```
line = "that`s not good thing ! you havn`t understand anything ?"
text=re.sub("[^\w]"," ",line).split()
```

but it can't work for desired output.  Please suggest something for the same.

Comment: I imagine this one string is not the only string your Python app will have to process. Could you explain a little more of what you are trying to do? Are you trying to remove punctuation characters and normalize the space in certain character sequences (like where "that's" is missing the single quote)?

Comment: Actully i don`t know why single quote not show in my post ?consider that s =that`s .And i want to tokenize the string i mean create the tokens .

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for this:

```
text = re.sub("[^\\w\\s]", "", line)
```

Note that you appear to want to keep the whitespace in addition to the regular characters.

Then if you are really after the words in the line, you can do the `text.split()`

Demo:

```
In [29]: line = "that`s not good thing ! you havn`t understand anything ?"

In [30]: text=re.sub("[^\\w\\s]","",line)

In [31]: text
Out[31]: 'thats not good thing  you havnt understand anything '

In [32]: text.split()
Out[32]: ['thats', 'not', 'good', 'thing', 'you', 'havnt', 'understand', 'anything']
```

Comment: :your solution not gives desire output .it separate out the chatracter after the single quote .Ex. that`s='that' 's' but i want 'thats'.

Comment: @Target: No it doesn't.  Note that the replacement is not a space, but the empty string, unlike the code in the original example.

Comment: If the answer works as required then go ahead and accept the answer.